# Way to measure the memory bandwidth for a certain instruction or code line in CUDA?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, memory-bandwidth

Is there a way to measure the memory bandwidth for a certain memory instruction or a code line in CUDA? (nvprof can output the memory bandwidth for an entire kernel.) If the clock() function is only way to do so, then what is the equation to calculate the bandwidth? (# of coalesced addresses per {instruction or code line} divided by clock() differences?)

I want to see if a certain instruction or a code line over/under-utilize the memory bandwidth. (ex, MSHR..)

I have two devices, GTX980 (Maxwell, sm_52) and P100 (Pascal, sm_60) on x86_64 bits linux system.

Comment: I'm not sure this makes much sense for a number of reasons.  Perhaps the most important one is that the LD (SASS) instruction is a fire-and-forget instruction.  That means that it is merely issued to the LD/ST unit, and *sometime later* a memory transaction may be triggered as a result of this.  If you simply measured the "duration" of the LD instruction, you are just measuring the time it takes to issue that instruction to the LD/ST unit - which should be quite short, just a few cycles if you can measure it accurately.  It's not actually representative of the time it takes to retrieve data.

Comment: There's no such thing as the memory bandwidth of an instruction or line of code (specifically, not LD/ST instructions). It is executed in sequence and in parallel to other instructions. Also - what @RobertCrovella said, so you can't get what you need from using `clock()`. Perhaps if you could explain what question you're trying to answer with this value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One tool that can give some insight is the instruction-level profiling in the nsight tool. It can give you an idea of which line to blame when the SM "stalls" (fails to issue any instruction). Because LD/ST instructions do not block execution, you often see the stall immediately *following* the data fetch.

Here's an NVIDIA devblog on the topic. https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-7-5-pinpoint-performance-problems-instruction-level-profiling/

Answer (score 2):

Use the visual profiler from nvidia.  More or less, it will tell you everything that it is possible to know about the performance of your cuda code.

If you compile your code with -lineinfo the profiler can tell you statistics for each line in a kernel. When you run your code, switch to unguided analysis (lower left in default layout). Let it generate the timeline, click on the kernel you want in the timeline, then click the play button for Global Memory Access Pattern in the lower left panel. It will come up with a per line listing of global memory loads, with transactions/access as well as inform you what the ideal number is. Double clicking on one of these lines will take you to the line in the source code and show you the matching assembly instructions.